# installing llvm on snow leopard

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, llvm

I just tried installing LLVM by following the steps mentioned [here](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-dev/wiki/Building), revision 42498 and there seems to be a problem as i "make". The error I get is as follows :-

```
llvm[2]: Bisoning llvmAsmParser.y
/Users/zm/repos/llvm-svn/lib/AsmParser/llvmAsmParser.y: conflicts: 4 shift/reduce
llvm[2]: Compiling Lexer.cpp for Release build 
In file included from /Users/zm/repos/llvm-svn/lib/AsmParser/Lexer.l:28:
/Users/zm/repos/llvm-svn/lib/AsmParser/ParserInternals.h:40: error: conflicting declaration ‘int llvmAsmleng’
Lexer.cpp:307: error: ‘llvmAsmleng’ has a previous declaration as ‘yy_size_t llvmAsmleng’
make[2]: *** [/Users/zm/repos/llvm-svn/lib/AsmParser/Release/Lexer.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [AsmParser/.makeall] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Has anyone had similar issues? If so, how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by changing the source to use "int" instead of "yy_size_t". However, the root of the problem is still not understood as "yy_size_t" is essentially an "unsigned int".